# Passing variables between functions within HTA

Tags: function, variables, vbscript, hta

I have created a HTA that will act as an application installer. I need to be able to pass a variable from one function to another, within the HTA. Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <script language="vbscript">
        set wsh=createobject("wscript.shell")
        set fso=createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        function htaresize
            height=480
            width=640
            window.resizeto width,height
            screenheight=document.parentwindow.screen.availheight
            screenwidth=document.parentwindow.screen.availwidth
            postop=(screenheight-height)/2
            posleft=(screenwidth-width)/2
            window.moveto posleft,postop
        end function
        htaresize()
        function window_onload
            sfl="_a.txt"
            set fil=fso.opentextfile(sfl,1)
            do until fil.atendofstream
                sln=fil.readline
                set opt=document.createelement("option")
                opt.text=sln
                opt.value=sln
                availapps.add(opt)
            loop
            fil.close
        end function
        function findsel
            sel=""
            for each i in availapps.options
                if i.selected then
                    sel=sel & i.value
                    sel=i.value
                end if
            next
            if len(sel)>0 then
                select case sel
                    case "7-Zip"
                    case "Adobe AIR"
                    case "Adobe Flash Player"
                    case "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"
                    case "Adobe Shockwave Player"
                    case "Cisco WebEx"
                    case "Citrix Receiver"
                    case "FileZilla"
                    case "Gimp"
                    case "Google Chrome"
                    case "InfraRecorder"
                    case "FolderSizes"
                    case "Microsoft Office"
                    case "Java"
                    case "Rufus"
                end select
                if len(sel)>0 then
                    jpg="<img src='./_dependencies/" & sel & ".jpg'>"
                    txt="<p>You have chosen to install " & sel & " on this computer.</p>"
                    war="<p>Please note - If User Account Control (UAC) is active on this system, some functions of this application may be restricted and/or non-functional. If installation fails or the application doesn't function as expected, try temporarily disabling your antivirus or security software and install again as antivirus or other security software could cause the installation to fail.</p><p>Continuing the installation of this software may impair or destabilize the correct operation of this system either immediately or in the future.</p>"
                    btn="<br><br><input class='button' name='button_cont' onclick='install' type='button' value='INSTALL'>"
                end if
                dataarea.innerhtml=jpg & txt & war & btn
            end if
        end function
        function install
            msgbox sel & " is now being installed. Please wait..."
            '* * * perform actual install procedure here * * *
        end function
    </script>
    <hta:application 
        applicationname="hta"
        border="none"
        borderstyle="normal"
        caption="yes"
        contextmenu="no"
        commandline=""
        icon=""
        id="hta"
        innerborder="no"
        maximizebutton="no"
        minimizebutton="no"
        navigable="yes"
        scroll="no"
        scrollflat="yes"
        selection="no"
        showintaskbar="no"
        singleinstance="yes"
        systemmenu="no"
        version="2016.11.07"
        windowstate="normal" />
    <head>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
            * {
                font:12px "Arial", "Calibri", "Franklin Gothic Book", "Gill Sans MT", "Lucida Sans", "Microsoft Sans Serif", "MS Outlook", "Tahoma", "Verdana" sans-serif;
            }
            html {
                background:#fff;
                color:#000;
                height:100%;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:100%;
            }
            body {
                border:1px solid #000;
                height:478px;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:638px;
            }
            a {
                text-decoration:none;
            }
            div#wrap {
                height:100%;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:100%;
            }
            div#top {
                background-color:#0066cb;
                border-bottom:1px solid #000;
                color:#000;
                height:40px;
                margin:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                padding:5px;
                text-align:center;
                width:628px;
            }
            div#top h1 {
                font-size:36px;
                font-weight:900;
                text-align:center;
            }
            div#left {
                background-color:#99cdff;
                border-right:1px solid #000;
                color:#000;
                float:left;
                height:385px;
                margin:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                padding:5px;
                text-align:center;
                width:187px;
            }
            div#right {
                float:right;
                height:365px;
                margin:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                padding:10px;
                text-align:center;
                vertical-align:middle;
                width:420px;
            }
            div#bottom {
                background-color:#0066cb;
                border-top:1px solid #000;
                height:21px;
                margin:0;
                overflow:hidden;
                padding:5px;
                text-align:right;
                width:628px;
            }
            span#dataarea {
                text-align:center;
                padding-top:187px;
            }
            .right-align {
                text-align:right;
            }
            .coltitle {
                font-size:14px;
                font-weight:900;
            }
            .indent {
                padding-left:30px;
            }
            .button {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                width:75px;
            }
        </style>
        <title>Application Installer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="top">
                <h1 class="right-align">APPLICATION INSTALLER</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="left">
                <br />
                <p class="coltitle">Available Applications</p>
                <select id="listbox" size="18" name="availapps"></select>
                <br /><br />
                <input class="button" name="select" type="button" onclick="findsel" value="SELECT">
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <span id="dataarea"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="bottom">
                <input class="button" name="button_exit" onclick="window.close" type="button" value="EXIT">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Therefore, the goal is to be able to read the "sel" variable, established within the "findsel" function, from within the "install" function.

Is this possible?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. At the beginning of the script section, prior to any of the functions, I added...

```
dim choice
```

Then, in the "findsel" function, I added...

```
choice=sel
```

Finally, in the "install" function, I modified...

```
msgbox sel & " is now being installed. Please wait..."
```

To...

```
msgbox choice & " is now being installed. Please wait..."
```

Thanx.